# get ID of pages administered by the user using access_token via facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have offline access_token for the user, I want to get the id's of all the pages administered by the user so that I can update the page status using the facebook API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `page_admin` table wit FQL to find the pages the user administers using the following:

```
SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()
```

In that example, you will get the list of pages administered by `me()` (you).

For more information about the `page_admin` table, have a look [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/). The same procedure can be done for domains as well using the [domain_admin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/domain_admin/) table.

You can test the query [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/).

Comment: thanks for answering, although I solved my problem using curl-php but I learned something new from your answer.